# Issue with graphics drivers after install

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have been having an issue and I hate to say Windows comes better :(

I have an old laptop HP Pavilion DV2000 to be exact I can install windows fine.

Windows XP, 8 and 8.1

Ubuntu 12.04 installs and runs fine but when it comes to upgrading here comes the issue.

I have tried installing 14.04 and 14.10 and both the same results as upgrading to 14.04

After install/upgrade I get an Ubuntu screen and then a black screen and then that is it. I can access terminal and when I go back to desktop the screen is still black (well with a working curser anyway)

I am suspecting graphics driver issues as being the suspect. To my knowledge my laptop is well within the recommended specs for Ubuntu and I know it is a resource hog but worse than windows I didn't think so.

Why Ubuntu? well I like the feel for it I like the look and I am using it also on my other laptop my desktop and my home server.

Any help would be great :)

Best regards

---

**EDIT

---

I can run low graphics mode

EDIT 2 output of lspci -v on working 13.10

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d4000000-d5ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000cfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at d6400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: d2000000-d3ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: 80000000-801fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080200000-00000000803fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff
    Memory behind bridge: d6000000-d60fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080400000-00000000805fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    I/O ports at 1800 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 1820 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at 1840 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 1860 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at d6404000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=64
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: d6100000-d61fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 03f4 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0374 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 1880 [size=16]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at 18c8 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 18ac [size=4]
    I/O ports at 18c0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 18a8 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 18b0 [size=16]
    Memory at d6404400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    I/O ports at 18e0 [size=32]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G72M [GeForce Go 7200] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d5000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at d4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at c8000000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

05:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at d6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945

08:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation PRO/100 VE Network Connection (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 66, IRQ 20
    Memory at d6100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: e100

08:09.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at d6101000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci

08:09.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 19)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
    Memory at d6101800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci

08:09.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at d6102000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r592

08:09.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30b2
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at d6102400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r852
```

I'm currently on 13.10 as it works but I don't like the fact that it's not supported :(I believe I have tried everything even installing the drivers from the nvidia site 304.88 but that fails assuming some kernel incompatibility.

I would still hope that I can upgrade to 14.04 but this is driving me crazy.

I do notice that the  drivers have different wording in 14.04/10

At the moment in additional drivers it says

> Using NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library from nvidia-304 (proprietary, tested)

But in 14.04 it has different wording

This is a HP Pavilion DV2000 with Nvidia GeForce go 7200 card 2gb ram. It is a fresh install with nothing else installed everything standard and the latest BIOS

---

EDIT 3

---

Ok finally got 14.04 installed and stable however I am using the driver from bumblebee ppa and the resolution is wrong and will not change. Does anyone know how to change?

I had 1280x800 on 13.10 but now only 1024x768

Thank you

Comment: Did you try 13.04/13.10? I had an older laptop that was OK on 12.04 but ng on 13.04. (graphics incomaptibility though I don't recall the details)

Comment: Thank you yes all seems not bad at the moment on 13.10. On 14.04 I could purge nvidia and reboot and my laptop would boot but would get hot. Just when ever I tried to install nvidia drivers again the issue would arrise. I tried all sorts of drivers and nothing was hoping someone could point to the best. One thing I notice on 12.10 and 13.10 it says xorg driver kernel module and vdpau etc blah 304 but it never said that on 14.x

Comment: @Fabby even when I had tried all that? Reading my original post including my edit it's definitely a graphics driver issue I had already searched Google and here a lot before my post here about this issue

Comment: Yes.  One of the solutions is [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) and that'll definitely help!

Comment: @Jinx13 - if it is a graphics issue please add the output of `lspci -v` [to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/587889/edit) and the details about your computer setup and graphics cards.

Comment: @Fabby none of those solutions worked unless I've missed something :( Thank you for your reply also

Comment: what's the output to `nvidia-settings --version` (version number only is enough...

Comment: Currently says 304.88 remembering this is a working 13.10. May have realised the issue actually. My version is correct as of the nvidia site but with 14.04 nvidia-current is 304.25 or something like that with no way I could see to install the 304.88 even direct from nvidia

Comment: Can you post your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, please? I'd also like to see the first line of the changelog file of the Nvidia drivers (`for f in /usr/share/doc/nvidia-*/changelog.Debian.gz; do echo -n "$f: "; zcat "$f" | head -n 1; done`)

Comment: I have managed to get 14.04 working. It's a incompatible kernel issue with 304.88 and 14.04 installed nvidia 304.125 which I have now. I have lost unity but that is a different question. Thank you for the help is the output still needed to be posted?

Comment: Added EDIT 3 if anyone knows a solution to my new issue :) Or a link as my google results don't turn anything interesting